# Yii2 Get Database with Array as an 'IN'

Tags: database, yii2

I want to show some datas in view, but there's an error

Here's my code

Controller :

First, i want to put some number in `$row`

```
$row = Table1::find('number')->where(['username' => Yii::$app->user->identity->username])->asArray();
```

Then, i want to find some datas in `Table2` with `$row` as an `IN`

```
$show = Table2::find()->where(['id_user' => $row])->all();
```

And, i render the `view`

```
return $this->render('view', ['show' => $show]);
```

View :

I use `foreach` to show `$show`

```
<?php
  foreach($show as $s):
?>

   <?= $s->data ?>

<?php
  endforeach;
?>
```

But it shows the error :

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: what mean find('number') ???? .. i think your query return nothing .. try var:dump($row) ..

Comment: 'number' is one of the column in Table1. It's like another condition of where. But i do not understand enough

Comment: $row = Table1::find()->select('number')->where(['username => Yii::$app->user->identity->username])->asArray(); : try this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error you're getting is caused by this by this code bit: `Table1::find('number')`
the argument you pass to `find()` needs to be a condition (expression, string or array format) just like `where()`

i'ts not clear from your question what you are doing with that particular query,
perhaps you need something like this:

```
Table1::find()->select(['number'])->where( ... );
```

Comment: Thanks... It works.. I just had no idea about the syntax in 'find()' function